# I would like upload an image from nativescript app to https apache server

Tags: php, nativescript

I find PHP script which transfer photo to server, but code not works, I see errors: *Undefined index: File-Name in /var/www/html/server/index.php on line 3* and  *file_put_contents(uploads/): failed to open stream: Is a directory in /var/www/html/server/index.php on line 4*. In php.ini file I've grant privileges to upload files, directory uploads exist, files on server have all permissions.

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
   $all_headers = apache_request_headers();
   $newimg = file_put_contents('uploads/' .$_FILES['File-Name'],
   file_get_contents('php://input'));
?>
```

**NativeScript code**

````
    image: string;
    public tasks: bgHttp.Task[] = [];
    private url: string;
    private counter: number = 0;
    private session: any;
    public events: { eventTitle: string, eventData: any }[] = [];
    constructor(
        private gallery: GalleryService,
        private params: ModalDialogParams,

    ) {
        this.image = gallery.newImgPath;
        this.url = "https://127.0.0.1/ser/";
        this.session = bgHttp.session("image-upload");


    }
    sendImage(){
        const name = this.image.substr(this.image.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
        const description = `${name}(${++this.counter})`;
        const request = {
            url: this.url,
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/octet-stream",
                "File-Name": name
            },
            description: opis,
            androidAutoDeleteAfterUpload: false,
            androidNotificationTitle: 'send images',
        };

        let task: bgHttp.Task;
        let lastEvent = "";
        task = this.session.uploadFile(this.image, request);
        function onEvent(e) {
            if (lastEvent !== e.eventName) {
                // suppress all repeating progress events and only show the first one
                lastEvent = e.eventName;
            } else {
                return;
            }

            this.events.push({
                eventTitle: e.eventName + " " + e.object.description,
                eventData: JSON.stringify({
                    error: e.error ? e.error.toString() : e.error,
                    currentBytes: e.currentBytes,
                    totalBytes: e.totalBytes,
                    body: e.data,
                    responseCode: e.responseCode
                })
            });
        }

        zadanie.on("Sending", onEvent.bind(this));
        zadanie.on("Error", onEvent.bind(this));
        zadanie.on("responded", onEvent.bind(this));
        zadanie.on("Send end", onEvent.bind(this));
        lastEvent = "";
        this.tasks.push(task);
    }
    ```
In request in Nativescript code, app sending headers to server, but it not works. I need to use https server, because from Android 9 http protocol not works.
````

Comment: Did you log `$_FILES['File-Name']`, see value?, I think you are suppose to access the file name on header, that's where you are putting it on your request.

Comment: @Manoj I tried `print_r($_FILES['File-Name'])`, but I saw only notice: _Undefined index: File-Name in /var/www/html/server/index.php on line 5_

Comment: @Manoj Is there any sensible way to send an image to a via PHP server ? I'm sending headers from app, but it don't work. I can't find sensible solution.